# XML to MySQL - data update (without duplicate)

Tags: php, mysql, xml, pdo

Whole story: I have often updated xml file with pruducts. I need that file, but only with some products. So now I made scripts which take the xml file, send its data to mysql and then make another xml file from them (+ I added another parameter to each product in table, so I have interface where I choose whitch products will be in new xml and which won't).
I had had nearly no experiences with php before that, so it took me many hours and the scripts look really bad, but it works. Almost.
My actual problem:
When I am trying check the original xml file and update data in MySQL, it works fine, but it doesn't only add new products and update the old ones, but it also adds all products again. I used CRON to update automaticaly, but now I have over 50k products in table instead of few hundreds. So I need edit my script, to add new products only when their ITEM_ID is not already in database. My actual code looks lie this: `

```
<?php 
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://www.xxx.yyy/");
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=wm100.wedos.net;dbname=d38383_xml", "a38383_xml", "*****");
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

foreach ($xml->SHOPITEM as $item) {
    
    $dotazText = "INSERT INTO xml(ITEM_ID, PRODUCTNAME, DESCRIPTION, URL, IMGURL, PRICE_VAT, MANUFACTURER, CATEGORYTEXT, CATEGORY_FULLNAME, DELIVERY_DATE, VAL)
                    VALUES ('$item->ITEM_ID','$item->PRODUCTNAME','$item->DESCRIPTION', '$item->URL','$item->IMGURL', '$item->PRICE_VAT','$item->MANUFACTURER', '$item->CATEGORYTEXT','$item->CATEGORY_FULLNAME','$item->DELIVERY_DATE','$item->VAL')";
    $update = "UPDATE xml SET `PRODUCTNAME`='$item->PRODUCTNAME', `DESCRIPTION`='$item->DESCRIPTION', `IMGURL`='$item->IMGURL', `PRICE_VAT`='$item->PRICE_VAT', `MANUFACTURER`='$item->MANUFACTURER', `CATEGORYTEXT`='$item->CATEGORYTEXT', `CATEGORY_FULLNAME`='$item->CATEGORY_FULLNAME', `DELIVERY_DATE`='$item->DELIVERY_DATE', `VAL`='$item->VAL'   WHERE ITEM_ID='$item->ITEM_ID'";               
    try {
    $db->query($dotazText);
    $db->query($update);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
            
}
include ("out.php");







?>
```

`
Thank you so much for helping me out. I am sure that there is some answer on the internet, but as I said - I have no php skills so I hardly understand what I am doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add an unique index for `ITEM_ID` or make it the primary key, you can use [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html), i.e. (shortened, add columns as required)

```
INSERT INTO xml(ITEM_ID, PRODUCTNAME, DESCRIPTION)
    VALUES ('$item->ITEM_ID','$item->PRODUCTNAME','$item->DESCRIPTION')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    PRODUCTNAME=VALUES(PRODUCTNAME),
    DESCRIPTION=VALUES(DESCRIPTION);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It is much easier than my tries I did before. And it works! May I have one more question? I have xml like this:

`              ....
  <PARM>
   <PARAM_NAME>Distribuce</PARAM_NAME>
   <VAL>CZ</VAL>
  </PARM>
  <PARM>
   <PARAM_NAME>Typ distribuce</PARAM_NAME>
   <VAL>elektronická</VAL>
  </PARM>
 </SHOPITEM>              
`

And I care only about <VAL>CZ</VAL> - the rest is always the same. How do I get this with simplexml? Whatever I do, this colum is blank.

Comment: If my answer helped you, please accept it. For the XML issue, please ask another question. On SO we like to have small, well defined questions and answers (so others can easily find and readily use). Besides that, I don't know SimpleXml :-)

Comment: @HugoMatoušek Any issue with this answer?

Comment: sorry. This was a long, long time ago (I was even stupid enough to post the DB password...) - I didn't even know how to use the site. I came across this today, so I accepted your answer.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for accepting after that many years :-) I‘ve to admit I didn‘t even see that there‘s a password. I would have pointed out / edited… 